# DROP Event Not firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

**DROP Event Not firing in First and Last Position**

I am using a UL where its LI are draggable and sortable. If i drag and drop the item in the middle then the drop event fires, but if i drop in the first or last position of the UL then the drop event is not firing. Thanks in advance.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.accordion.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.droppable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.sortable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Styles/whereabouts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/demos.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<style>
#draggable { width: 16em; padding: 0 1em; }
#draggable ul li { margin: 1em 0; padding: 0.5em 0; } * html #draggable ul li { height: 1%; }
#draggable ul li span.ui-icon { float: left; }
#draggable ul li span.count { font-weight: bold; }
</style>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".ui-state-default").draggable();
            $(".ui-helper-reset").droppable({
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    alert('dropped');
                }
            }).sortable();
        });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="ui-helper-reset">
<li id="event-start" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-play">    </span>"start" invoked <span class="count">0</span>x</li>
<li id="event-drag" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4"></span>"drag" invoked <span class="count">0</span>x</li>
<li id="event-stop" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-stop">
</span>"stop" invoked <span class="count">0</span>x</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you aren't triggering the drop, you'd be triggering the sortables stop event. I feel like what you have is a bit redundant anyway, why just use the sortable by itself?

Comment: @jack : In my real application I am using my logic to do some validation and I have to multiple UL in my real application. That is the reason i use the drop event.

Comment: I see, check out the sortables, stop event, that might be what you're after.

Comment: My requirement is i need to revert the LI to its original position if my validation fails.  from STOP event shall we able to do validation? if yes how we can all call revert .

Comment: AFAIK you can't have draggable and sortable at the same time, it doesn't make sense. Also, the reason the alert isn't going off is because you are setting the ul to be droppable but that only works if the item is dropped inside that ul's area. This fiddle demonstrates my point: http://jsfiddle.net/q7yBn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not the answer for the questions.

Actually i moved my drop event code to stop event code of the Sorttable() and my requirement is fulfilled in my real application. Thank you all.